# I want to create a search option for CPT using plugin. The search options should search for categories and tags

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, search

I want to create a search option for CPT using a plugin. Currently, the plugin displays data from the CPT posts using custom Gutenberg blocks. I am also able to display all post lists. I need to filter the post using the search form. The search options should search for categories and tags. Ideally, I want to display the search form using a Gutenberg block. What is the correct way to do it? I am new to plugin development. Plz advice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your cpt to the search query ?

```
function include_cpt_in_search($query) {
  if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query())
    return;

  if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'your_custom_post_type'));
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'include_cpt_in_search');
```

Comment: I want to create the search as a Gutenberg Block ...